# Deploy github repo with herouku get error: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I've found around about this error. But I can't find a solution to my situation.

My `index.js` has `process.env.PORT` and in my `package.json` already has version of node and yarn.

But I still receive the error below.

[image: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"]

Here is my repo: https://github.com/Hubert-EC/HubertBE

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "UTE1.21-EC18A009-BE",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/lvminh/UTE1.21-EC18A009-BE",
  "author": "theleehari <nhai30928@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.5",
    "yarn": "1.22.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.5.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-facebook-token": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-google-plus-token": "^2.1.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "paypal-rest-sdk": "^1.8.1",
    "query-string": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

and here is my `index.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const connectDb = require("./common/connectDb");
const app = express();
//const { PORT} = require("./common/config");
const router = require("./router/index.router");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use("/api", router);

connectDb();

app.use("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hubert"));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hubert");
});
app.get("/test-paypal", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/services/Paypal.Services.html");
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listen on port ${port}`));
```

Here is my function `connectDb()`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { MONGODB_URI } = require("./config");

const connectDb = async () => {

  await mongoose
    .connect(MONGODB_URI, {
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => console.log("Success!!!!"))
    .catch((error) => console.error("Failed: ", error));
};

module.exports = connectDb;
```

here is my `.env`

```
#Connect MongoDB
MONGODB_URI = 

#PORT LISTEN
PORT = 8080

#nodemailer config
ADMIN_EMAIL = 
ADMIN_EMAIL_PASSWORD = 
PORT_SEND_MAIL = 

#Json web token value
JWT_SECRET= 

#Google OAuth token
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = 
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = 

#Facebook OAuth token
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID = 
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET = 

#URL
CLIENT_URL = 


#PAYPAL SANDBOX
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID = 
PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. It's in `package.json` file.
Because `nodemon` is placed in `devDependencies`.
So we must:

Replace

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app/index.js"
  },
```

with

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app/index.js",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check function connectDb(), use try/catch to show the error. Can you show me file .env and connectDb

Comment: I have just edited my post. About file `.env`, your mean is my key?

Comment: yeah I think the connect mongo error because URL depends on file env, but env doesn't upload on Heroku due to file .gitignore has to remove file env, you can remove ```.env``` in gitignore after retry

Comment: MonogURL you has use mongo cloud or local?

Comment: I use cloud. It's Mongo Atlas

Comment: You try to remove line .env in gitignore

Comment: Can you take a photo of an error ```heroku logs --tail```

Comment: oh, I think I know the error, you missing a Procfile, you must be created Procfile to start the server content file : ```web: npm start``` and you need to add ```"start": "node app/index.js"``` in the script in file package.json

Comment: I already have `"start": "node app/index.js"` in `package.json`. I deploy my app with repo github. So I think I don't need `Procfile`

Comment: Can you tell me where I can run `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: if you deploy Heroku by CLI so in root project open cmd and type ```heroku logs --tail```
You will see logs of heroku

Comment: I deploy by github repo. Is there another solution?